# Duplicated entities in Core Data after terminating the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm having a very consistent bug in my application:
When I store some data in the Core Data and terminated the app, then run it again some of the data is been duplicated. I debugged the code line by line in the sensitive places and realized that terminating the app causes the last edited data to be duplicated.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: since you already know "that terminating the app causes the last edited data to be duplicated" why can't you just fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When debugging core data apps, remember that just clicking "run" again or stopping the app terminates it immediately - there are no app delegate methods executed, so your context is probably not being saved.

Try to remember to click the home button before terminating the app or re-running from Xcode. This way your context will be saved. Your app will not normally be terminated "in the wild", it is just an artefact of your testing / debugging process.

Comment: Though do remember that apps can crash so you should be able to recover from this happening ;)